# Queue and Stack in Computer Science and relation to MATH

Tags: computer-science, data-analysis

For Creating a Queue Q we use two Stack S1,S2. for insert x in the end of Q we do Push(S1,x). for deleting element from front of Q, (if Q is not empty) we do Pop(S2). if on Q that at first is empty, we do 100 operation (insert or delete from front or end or arbitrary sequence). What is the maximum Cost? each Pop and Push is 1 Cost.

My solution:

i think 50 push and 50 pop * 2 =200.

any idea or solution highly appreciated.

Comment: is your answer worng, what the correct answer, your answer seems right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each operation costs 1, we can gain maximum when all operations do some pushing/popping. The best way to do is 50 push and 50 pops which correspond to $50\times1+50\times1=100$

Comment: @Okh.Pij how can you get 200?

Comment: @Okh.Pij you did 4 operation for cost of 4, you can only do it 25 more times as $25\times4=100$ but you are saying to do 50 times